# How to reduce blocking during concurrent DELETE & INSERT to a single table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency, sql-server-2016, database-partitioning

We have a stored procedure which loads order details about an order. We always want the latest information about an order, so order details for the order are regenerated every time, when the stored procedure is called. We are using SQL Server 2016.

Pseudo code:

- DELETE by clustered index based on order identifier
- INSERT into the table, based on a huge query containing information about order

When multiple end-users are executing the stored procedure concurrently, there is a blocking created on `orderdetails` table. Once the first caller is done, second caller is queued, followed by third caller. So, the time for the generation of the `orderdetails` increases as time goes by. This is happening especially in the cases of big orders containing details rows in > 100k or 1 or 2 million, as there is table level lock is happening.

**The approach we took**

We partitioned the table based on the last digit of the order identifier for concurrent `orderdetails` loading. This improves the performance in the case of first time `orderdetails` loading, as there are no deletes. But, second time onwards, `INSERT` in first session is causing blocking for other sessions `DELETE`. The other sessions are blocked till first session is done with `INSERT`.

We are considering creation of separate `orderdetails` table for every order to avoid this concurrency issues.

**Question**

Can you please suggest some approach, which will support concurrent `DELETE` & `INSERT` scenario ?

Comment: You are using SQL Server 2016. Get the SP1 and start using hekaton?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try hekaton, In-Memory capabilities

Comment: Discussed with my boss here. We are having limited memory and being used for other operations and does not want to use in-memory OLTP. I am trying to use partition switch to see whether it succeeds.

Comment: Could not try with partition switch, as it expects destination partition to be empty. Went ahead with temporary table loading followed by DELETE, INSERT

Comment: @gotqn, it is very good suggestion. can you please add as answer, I will upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved the contention issue by going for temporary table for `orderdetails`. We found that huge queries are taking longer *SELECT* time and this longer time was contributing to longer table level locks on the `orderdetails` table.

So, we first loaded data into temporary table `#orderdetail` and then went for DELETE and INSERT in the `orderdetail` table.

As the `orderdetail` table is already partitioned, *DELETE* were faster and *INSERT* were happening in parallel. *INSERT* was also very fast here, as it is simple table scan from `#orderdetail` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a look to the [Hekaton Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization). It is available even in `SQL Server Standard Edition` if you are using `SP1`.

If this is too complicated for implementation due to hardware or software limitations, you can try to play with the [Isolation Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) of the database. Sometimes, queries that are reading huge amount of data are blocked or even deadlock victims of queries which are modifying parts of these data. You can ask yourself do you need to guarantee that the data read by the user is valid or you can afford for example some dirty reads?